# How do I make `& non_existent_cmd` (the call operator) a terminating error?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Given this script:

```
& non_existent_cmd
echo "I don't want this to run"
```

What's the easiest way to raise a non-terminating error when running `& non_existent_cmd` so that the following `echo` command never runs.

For reference, the script (as written above) currently outputs:

```
& : The term 'non_existent_cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & non_existent_cmd
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (non_existent_cmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I don't want this to run
```

Comment: I would add that you can use `Get-Command` first to determine whether a command exists. Then I don't think you need to trap errors.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart that could work too. One limitation with that approach is that `Get-Command` won't reveal a problem if the command exists but isn't executable, or maybe if there's a race condition where command exists but is then deleted.

Comment: It seems to me that writing workaround code (trap error for nonexistent command) due to a theoretically possible (but extremely rare) race condition is not a sufficient cost/benefit ratio compared with `Get-Command`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I don't disagree, in many cases. However, in the cleanup script I'm writing, if `& git.exe ...` returns no output and execution continues, many things will be deleted, which would be bad. Nevermind the race condition, I **can** imagine a situation where the executable exists but is not executable.

Comment: Lots of things _could_ happen. There are also lots of things that are extremely unlikely...

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `$ErrorActionPreference` of your session to `Stop`.  This will make any error a terminating one.

If you only want that call to terminate on error, you could do something like this:

```
$eap = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
& non_existent_cmd
echo "I don't want this to run"
$ErrorActionPreference = $eap
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this ?

```
try { & non_existent_cmd }
catch { Break }
"I don't want this to run"
```

Comment: `try..catch` could work. Only tweak I'd make is that in my case I do want the error to be raised, so I'd change `Break` to `Throw`.

Comment: @MichaelKropat Rather than throwing the error in the `catch` block echo whatever error information you're interested in, then `exit` from the script.

Comment: That was my first choice. But `Throw`ing inside `catch` seemed weird (and ugly) to me `:-)`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers A command not being found is not necessarily a fatal error. I've written a script before that has fallback functionality. I'd ideally like to write a function wrapper for `& non_existent_cmd` that throws a terminating error so it's up to the caller to decide if it's a fatal vs recoverable error.